# Staircase Timer with On/Off switches

Tags: switches, timer

I want to build a circuit for my home. The setup is as follows: I've got a circuit in my house, I can turn my lights on and off with switches from different positions. I'd like to have them switched off automatically after, say, five minutes, in case I forget them on, just like it works with staircase lamps.

It seems quite challenging to me, especially if I only limit myself to mechanical spring switches, step by step relays and timers (delay relays). Could such a circuit be possible to realize only with analogic components? Am I forced to use digital electronics?

Thanks!

Edit: clarification: at any given time, I want to be able to switch the lights on and off arbitrarily, just as I would do with my living room lights, except that I want them to turn off automatically after a given interval of time.

Comment: Mains voltage is dangerous.  Rather purchase off-the-shelf products and have them installed by an electrician.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am just wondering if it would be possible, as a thought experiment. The setup is not real. Although, this is a question which was proposed to me by an electrician.

Comment: I think you can Google NB-IoT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions.

I managed to write down the schematics for what I wanted to achieve. I used a Step Relay and a Time-Delay Relay. The solution is as follows: L1 is always switched off or on by pressing P. If it is left on, on time-out the Step Relay is switched, which resets the timer and switched the light off. The Time-Delay Relay is "ON delay".[image: Schematics for the circuit]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. A pneumatic time delay-off switch typically used for stairwells. This model is for the British standard wall box.*

There are no electronics. You press in the plunger which closes the electrical contacts. The plunger is pushed out by a spring at a rate determined by a pneumatic bleed valve which controls the rate that air re-enters the piston. When the button is close to fully out the contacts are opened.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNC9BW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. What you've got and what you want.*

Comment: Thank you. However I might not be specific enough. At any given time,  I want to be able to switch the lights off. This, apparently to me, blocks me from turning them off arbitrarily. I am going to update my question.

Comment: Yes, you weren't specific enough.